# Twitter username input field text filtering

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

Does anybody know how the username input field of [Twitter](http://twitter.com/) works? In the registration form, if you type any UTF-8 character it will not be rendered. How is that done?

Answer (score 4):

Javascript validation.

Comment: Yes, fiXedd is right :) The code is here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/twitter_production/a/1253569923/javascripts/signup.js?1253571264

Comment: @George, then what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the functions listed [here](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/), in conjunction with some other Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following jQuery code for my site. It differs slightlty from Twitter as they allow underscores and I don't.

`$(function(){
    $('input[name="username"]').keydown(function(key){
        if (jQuery.inArray(key.keyCode, [8,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90]) == -1 || key.shiftKey ){
            return false;
        }
    });
});`

Comment: Ok, that javascript looks horrible. Any tips on making it look nice?

Answer (score 0):

**$('.sample2').alphanumeric({allow:"., "});**

this code only allow to type alpha numeric and alow some special characters

**sample2** this is your text field class

include required files

```
jquery.js
jquery.alphanumeric.pack.js
```

you can get these files from below link

> http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/

i hope this will help you